# Mailchimp API v3 python Campaign List

Tags: python, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to filter campaigns based on list id via the API. I'm using the given example at https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/campaigns/list-campaigns/

However, when I input the parameter, I get the error

```
TypeError: list() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am only inputting one parameter.

I tried a few different criteria for the "list" arguement but they all return the same error. Sample code below

```
import mailchimp_marketing as MailchimpMarketing
from mailchimp_marketing.api_client import ApiClientError

try:
  client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
  client.set_config({
    "api_key": "xyz",
    "server": "xyz"
  })

  response = client.campaigns.list({"campaigns": [{"recipients": {"list_id": "xyz"}}]})
  print(response)
except ApiClientError as error:
  print("Error: {}".format(error.text))
```

```
import mailchimp_marketing as MailchimpMarketing
from mailchimp_marketing.api_client import ApiClientError

try:
  client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
  client.set_config({
    "api_key": "xyz",
    "server": "xyz"
  })

  response = client.campaigns.list([{"recipients": {"list_id": "xyz"}}])
  print(response)
except ApiClientError as error:
  print("Error: {}".format(error.text))
```

```
import mailchimp_marketing as MailchimpMarketing
from mailchimp_marketing.api_client import ApiClientError

try:
  client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
  client.set_config({
    "api_key": "xyz",
    "server": "xyz"
  })

  response = client.campaigns.list({"recipients": {"list_id": "xyz"}})
  print(response)
except ApiClientError as error:
  print("Error: {}".format(error.text))
```

```
import mailchimp_marketing as MailchimpMarketing
from mailchimp_marketing.api_client import ApiClientError

try:
  client = MailchimpMarketing.Client()
  client.set_config({
    "api_key": "xyz",
    "server": "xyz"
  })

  response = client.campaigns.list({"list_id": "xyz"})
  print(response)
except ApiClientError as error:
  print("Error: {}".format(error.text))
```

Appreciate any help into this.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to hear from you but I think you're confusing something i.e. you cant get campaigns in Mailchimp by **list_id**.

**For example**

```
response = client.campaigns.list() // This will return all campaigns
response = client.campaigns.get({campaign_id}) // This will return specific campaign
```

**Note:** In maximum APIs word **list** means ***to get all***

And in Mailchimp sdk there is no such method to get campaign using list_id: [LINK](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-python)

> And last thing about your error is that message has umpteen causes; the
> specific reason here is that all instance methods expect a first arg
> which by custom we call **self**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Adam, referring to the documentation (the link in the question), "list_id" is stated as a query parameter. Does this mean that the query parameter is not meant to filter the call?

Comment: Let me explore it more

Comment: Im in favor of my own answer. I'm trying to get in contact with mailchimp support.

Comment: @AdamStrauss its been a long time but anything you remember you got from mailchimp support?